# How to auto compile .less with a batch file

Tags: css, compilation, less

I'm using less for my project and every time i  want to compile i have to write this on Command line:

lessc app.less > app.css

Is there a solution to compile with a .bat file, every time i save the less file, without typing it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can some one help me please?

Comment: Usually we use tools like `Grunt` to do this for us (e.g. `grunt-contrib-watch` -> `grunt-contib-less` etc.). And there're a lot of tools for "watching" beside this (something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=less+css+watch) should help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile LESS code automatically in [many ways](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less-specific-platforms), with a GUI like [WinLESS](https://github.com/marklagendijk/WinLess), or via shell using something like [Grunt](http://lesscss.org/usage/#third-party-compilers).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a `.bat` file with the code below in the same directory that you have the main `less` and `css` files. After that click it everytime you need to compile it.

```
@echo off

start /b lessc --verbose --source-map style.less style.css

pause
```